# How can I create my own events in my C# application like the default ones available?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I needed to update the system tray icon's text value, of my application, whenever a user hovers over it. I noticed that no such event exists for system tray icons. Is it possible to create a hover event for a system tray icon and if so how can I go about accomplishing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about hooking into `NotifyIcon.MouseMove`?

As a basic example, this seems to work (with a `NotifyIcon` on a `Form`):

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        notifyIcon1.MouseMove += delegate
        {
            notifyIcon1.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        };
        notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Hand;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;            
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, but I was going for "rocker" ;-p

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, UI Elements have a ToolTipOpening/ToolTipClosing event. You should update the tooltip text in the opening. I don't know if system tray icons have such behavior, but i guess there is something similar.